# Echo conditional text based on day and time

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time, shortcode

I have some text I would like to echo based on the time of the day and day of the week.

On Monday it should say between 13.00 and 17.00: We zijn vandaag bereikbaar tot 17.00 uur.

On Tuesday till Friday it should say the same as above but then from 09.00 till 17.00.

Before 13.00 on Monday and 9.00 on Tuesday till Friday and after 17.00 and in weekends it should say: We zijn momenteel gesloten. Stuur een e-mail en we nemen z.s.m. contact met je op.

This is what I created to get a shortcode for it (Wordpress):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

function customer_service_phone (){
    $dateOfWeek = date('w');
    $time = date('H');
    if ($dateOfWeek == '1' && $time > '13' && $time < '17') {
        $availability = "We zijn vandaag bereikbaar tot 17.00 uur.";
    } elseif ($dateOfWeek > '1' && $dateOfWeek < '6' && $time > '9' && $time < '17'){
        $availability = "We zijn vandaag bereikbaar tot 17.00 uur.";
    } else {
        $availability = "We zijn momenteel gesloten. Stuur een e-mail en we nemen z.s.m. contact met je op.";
    }
    echo esc_attr( $availability );
}
add_shortcode ( 'availability_phone', 'customer_service_phone' );
```

This code works not entirely good. Because after 17.00 it still says the text for before 17.00.
What could it be? My servertime is correct with my timezone and also the time in Wordpress settings is the same. Timezone is Amsterdam.

Hope someone can help me with this. Any help would be appreciated.
Sorry if I didn't explain it clear enough.

Kind regards,
Vasco

Comment: This doesn't make sense $day >= 'Mon'. What did you try to do there?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to PHP. I try to define Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
function customer_service_phone (){
    $dateOfWeek = date('N');
    $time = date('H');
    if ($dateOfWeek == '1' && $time >= '13' && $time < '17') {
        $availability = "We zijn vandaag bereikbaar tot 17.00 uur.";
    } elseif ($dateOfWeek > '1' && $dateOfWeek < '6' && $time >= '09' && $time < '17'){
        $availability = "We zijn vandaag bereikbaar tot 17.00 uur.";
    } else {
        $availability = "We zijn momenteel gesloten. Stuur een e-mail en we nemen z.s.m. contact met je op.";
    }
    echo esc_attr( $availability );
}
add_shortcode ( 'availability_phone', 'customer_service_phone' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately I get the same result as with my code.

Comment: I added `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');` to the code which set the time correct and I added `('w')` instead of `('N')`. But it looks like it's not showing the if statement when I change the number of week to 5 (Friday, today) for testing. But it do show the else if correctly. I also updated the code above.